# Use SPARQL to query an existing Neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, sparql

I would like to query an existing Neo4j graph using SPARQL. This graph has been constructed using Neo4j statement like `MERGE` etc. So I want to keep the graph as it is and only add a SPARQL endpoint to it.

What I do **NOT** want to do is re-ingesting all the data for the SPARQL query to work.

I found a SPARQL extension for Neo4j here: https://github.com/niclashoyer/neo4j-sparql-extension, so my question is:

- will this extension work for me?
- If not, has Neo4j other plugin or extension to create a SPARQL endpoint for an existing graph?

Thank you!

Comment: This plugin is 5 years old and for version `2.1.5`, latest version on the other hand is `3.5.4` - I doubt it will work -> the answer is also in one of the [Github issues](https://github.com/niclashoyer/neo4j-sparql-extension/issues/50) - the projects is dead and it can't be adapted to 3.x because of major changes like Tinkerpop 3

Comment: I'm not aware of other plugins, but nowadays there is some research w.r.t. converting SPARQL to either Gremlin or Cypher as query language for property graphs.

Comment: And then, we also have commercial projects like GraphScale on top of Neo4J, with support for querying and reasoning.

Comment: Thank you for the info! But suppose I downgrade my Neo4j to `2.1.5`, will the plugin work as I have asked?

Comment: ```but nowadays there is some research w.r.t. converting SPARQL to either Gremlin or Cypher as query language for property graphs.```
Can you list a project explicitly here please? (converting SPARQL to Cypher)

Comment: Recent versions of Apache TinkerPop include a [SPARQL-Gremlin feature](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/reference/#sparql-gremlin) that sounds like it might be of use?

Comment: @cygri Yes, for SPARQL to Gremlin, the [Gremlinator](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.02911.pdf) is now integrated into Tinkerpop. But that won't work with Neo4j which uses Cypher and afaik I'm not aware of a Gremlin to Cypher converter as Gremlin supports some declarative traversal features beyond Cypher. But honestly, I didn't check research last half a year so it's likely I'm not up-to-date in that direction

Answer (score 0):

It's technically possible to use Tinkerpop to add SPARQL support to Neo4j although I haven't yet tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I would currently recommend using neosemantics (https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/4.0/validation/) because it supports rdf. Additionally  all sparql neo4j project seem to be abandoned as the commentators already stated, so you don´t seem to have many other options.